# Diverging or converging sequence?

Tags: calculus

Determine the value of the expression:

$\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-...}}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }  a_{n} $

A. Solve the problem intuitively. (recursion)
B. Give a formal argument. (use the definition of a converging sequence)

I am supposed to use a recursive expression for A and would appreciate some help to point me in the right direction 'cause I'm lost at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $$\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{2-...}}}= a$$

We have $\frac{1}{2-a}=a$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Ashot's answer, you'll need to construct a monotone increasing sequence (because we know that such sequences with an upper bound have a limit).

The following is a monotonically increasing sequence

$$(\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2}}, \frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2}}},\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2}}}},\cdots)$$

For our upper bound, we'll use $2$.

Comment: Thanks! I cracked the code :)